# PHP Cache refresh without restarting Apache

Tags: php, apache

A few of my sites seems to have server-side cache and I keep having to restart the `httpd` server every time I make changes to the PHP code

Is there a way not to restart Apache but have PHP code changes show up instantly?

Comment: Do you use API? If so, check apc.stat configuration option, it should be set to 1.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat

Comment: What cache are you using?

Answer (score 0):

7 years ago..
I'm not sure you would read this or not.
But I think what you want was changing opcache.enable option.

Go to `php/etc/php.ini` and try to change `opcache.enable=0`

But I think you'd better do that for development, not real services.